# What's is the best way to create indexes for the query below

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing

I have this query:

```
select * from `metro_stations`
where `is_active` = 1
  and (`title` like '%search%' or `title_en` like '%search%')
```

How to create effective indexes if `is_active` is TINYINT field and titles are VARCHAR(255) ?

And what about this query:

```
select * from `metro_stations`
where `is_active` = 1
 and (`title` like '%search%' or
      `title_en` like '%search%' or
      `description` like '%search%')
```

if description field is text?

Comment: `'%search%` is not SARGable. Think about full text index

Comment: FYI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable. `LIKE` is SARGable but only with `%` at the end `search%` see some sample here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use full text index for each column.
If use in query "or" use seperately fts index, if use "and" mix fts index (in one index use several column)
[Full Text Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html)

Comment: i added two different full text indexes for title and title_en fields, but query:

EXPLAIN EXTENDED select `id` from `metro_stations` where `is_active` = 1 and (`title` like "%мото%" or `title_en` like "%мото%")

doesn't seem to use indexes. How is it possible ?

Comment: select id from metro_stations WHERE match(title) against('мото'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: OK, its my mistake. Thank You!
What about performance ? Is this decision better than using LIKE '%search%' without any indexes ?

Comment: Performance analysis of MySQL's FULLTEXT indexes and LIKE queries for full text search http://makandracards.com/makandra/12813-performance-analysis-of-mysql-s-fulltext-indexes-and-like-queries-for-full-text-search

Comment: Read this but don't understand about InnoDB and MyISAM. My table has InnoDB engine. Can I use indexes in this situation ?

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6 and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Check your mysql version

Comment: Don't forget to mark as Answered (with green check mark) that which solves your problem or answers it otherwise (like the Q you had from 2013)

Comment: Marked as Answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FULLTEXT(title, title_en)

WHERE is_active = 1
  AND MATCH(title, title_en) AGAINST ("+search" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(This should work for either InnoDB (5.6+) or MyISAM.)

Keep in mind the limitations of "word length" and "stop words" in FULLTEXT.